# Set the "test" profile when run "mvn test"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm using Spring's `@Profile` to separate test-related classes from dev and prod. I'm having troubles finding a way to set `spring.profiles.active` to `test` in pom.xml, for `test` goal only. In other words, if the maven goal is `test` I want to run this:

```sh
mvn test
```

and still get to classes annotated @Profile("test"),
instead of this:

```sh
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

As it specifies "test"-nature of the run twice.

Is it even possible?

**UPDATE**: added code

Following two services are for tests and dev/prod. Both implement same interface MyService

MyService for test  environment:

```java
@Service
@Profile("test")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestMyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
  public String myMethod(){
    ...
    }
}
```

MyService for dev environment:

```java
@Service
public class DevMyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
  public String myMethod(){
    ...
    }
}
```

Controller that autowires the MyService:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping 
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

@RequestMapping(value = /myendpoint, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Response foo(@RequestBody String request) {
        Response response = new Response();
    response.setResult(myService.myMethod());
    return response;
  }
}
```

Test that tests MyController:

```java
@Test
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class MyControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @LocalServerPort
  int randomServerPort;

  @BeforeSuite
  public void config () {

  }


  @Test
  public void testFoo() throws Exception {

    final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/myendpoint";
    URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    headers.set("X", "true");
    ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
  }
}
```

application.properties that is in test/resources directory:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Comment: why not `@Profile` annotation on test class so that it will pick that profile automatically ?

Comment: @Deadpool Not sure that I got your question correctly... I'm annotating test class (@Profile("test")). But I have to specify, what profile to be used. Classic way is -Dspring.profiles.active=test, now I want it to set automatically when I run `mvn test` command, i.e. without having to set this parameter (because it is obviously a test run).

Comment: Try using @ActiveProfiles instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotation for running test classes with test profile follow the below steps

**Step 1:** Annotate all the test classes with `@Profile("name")` and `@ActiveProfiles("name")`

- `Profile` annotation is used to pick up the specified profile
- `ActiveProfiles` is used to activate specified profile for test classes

**Step 2:** Create `application.properties` or `application.yml` with profile name like **application-test.yml** and place it inside `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` with test properties

Comment: Should be @ActiveProfiles though :)

But you are correct.

Comment: No worries. I tried to edit, but had to be atleast 6 edits for it to go through.

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool and Pajala. I tried this and get "No qualifying bean of type [<classname>]is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2" (one of them annotated with both @Profile("test") and @ActiveProfiles("test")

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. I should have annotated second class as well (the one for dev). It works. Thanks! One thing I didn't get though... Now I'm removing both @ActiveProfiles annotation and "spring.profiles.active=test" from application.properties - and it still arrives to the TestMyServiceImpl - how does it know that the active profile is test?

Comment: there is no need of this property `spring.profiles.active=test` in `application.properties` and from where did you removed `@ActiveProfiles` ?

Comment: from TestMyServiceImpl

Comment: if there is no need, then what did you mean "Create application.properties with profile name"? There is a way of specifying spring profile other than `spring.profiles.active`?

Comment: Updated let me know if you have any questions @VicK

Comment: Assume we are running with spring.profiles.active=test.
If the junit test is being picked because it has `@Profile("test")` annotation, then whats the use of `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation? since `test` profile is already active.